# Django Limit Queryaset Objects by Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

Sorry for this question but I'm reasonably new to Django and it's eluding me. I am updating a system (think school) with users, classes (the teachable kind), etc. I have classes from the legacy system I want to bring into the new system, and I need to limit the list by a legacy_user_id. So far, I have this in
`models.py`

```
from account.models import Profile, LegacyUser

class OldClassesManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(LegacyUser.legacy_id)

class OldInstructables(models.Model):
    legacy_user_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,  blank=False)
[other stuff]

    objects = models.Manager()
    SOMETHING = OldClassesManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this in `views.py`

```
class OldClassList(ListView):
    model = OldInstructables
```

I think my problem is that I don't know what goes where I put `SOMETHING`. Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you have a `LegacyUser` that is the user model?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, I should have added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not filter in the manager, or at least not without a method with a parameter, since models are (normally) request-unaware.

You can filter in the view with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class OldClassList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = OldInstructables

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super().get_queryset().filter(legacy_user_id=self.request.user.legacy_id)
        )
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequiredmixin-mixin).

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `OldClassListView`, instead of <s>`OldClassList`</s>.

Comment: Something isn't working-- it says request is undefined in this context. I tried ```def get_queryset(request): ``` on the off chance that was the problem. No dice. Thanks for the 2nd note btw. I have to start being better about such things.

Comment: @JJRyan: yes, it was `self.request.user`, so with `self.`, not with a `request` parameter.

Comment: Ok this didn't work either but I think it goes back to your first question (about user). I looked back at the account app and I have a Profile model (which has the legacy_id field) which has a 1-to-1 relationship with the default User model. Sorry about the mixup; it's been a bit since I created that part of the app and I thought it was an extension, not a separate model. Can I access the Profile model from the request somehow or am I out of luck? Thanks for all your help btw.

Comment: @JJRyan: ah, then it is `self.request.user.profile.legacy_id` I think.

Answer (score -1):

1- The 'OldClassesManager'

```
 class OldClassesManager(models.Manager):
     def get_queryset(self):
         return super().get_queryset().filter(legacy_user_id=self.model.legacy_user_id)
```

2- The 'OldClassList' view:

```
 class OldClassList(ListView):
     model = OldInstructables

     def get_queryset(self):
         legacy_user_id = # get the legacy_user_id from wherever you want
         return OldInstructables.SOMETHING.get_queryset(legacy_user_id)
```

Comment: Tried this as well. Gave this error: ```TypeError: OldClassesManager.get_queryset() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given``` but I can't figure out why.